# Problems with user agent on urllib

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, urllib

I wanted to get the HTML of web site but I cant get it due to the user agent I suppose. Because when I call uClient=ureq(my_url) I get an error like this: urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

This is the code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as ureq, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url= 'https://hsreplay.net/meta/#tab=matchups&sortBy=winrate'

ureq(Request(my_url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0'}))


uClient=ureq(my_url)
page_html=uClient.read()
uClient.close()

html=soup(page_html,"html.parser")
```

I have tried other methods of changing th user agent and other user agents, but it isn't work.

I'm pretty sure you will help. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did above is clearly a mess. The code should not run at all. Try the below way instead.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request,urlopen

URL = "https://hsreplay.net/meta/#tab=matchups&sortBy=winrate"

req = Request(URL,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
res = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"lxml")
name = soup.find("h1").text
print(name)
```

Output:

```
HSReplay.net
```

Btw, you can scrape few items that are not `javascript encrypted` from that page. However, the core content of that page are generated dynamically so you can't grab them using `urllib` and `BeautifulSoup`. To get them you need to choose any browser simulator like `selenium` etc.

Comment: You can use `soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"html.parser")` instead of `soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"lxml")`. I did it cause [lxml](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) is faster.